# proof that nxn matrix is invertible by showing null space of left hand multiplication matrix to equal 0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

If I want to show that an $n$ x $n$ matrix $A$ is invertible then why is it that $$N(L_A)=\{0\}$$ proves that $A$ is invertible?  and $N(L_a)$ denotes the null space of the left hand matrix multiplication.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because if $L_A$ is injective then it's also surjective and so bijective due to the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: I tried looking up the proof for that but could not find it for some reason.  Could you post a link or briefly describe it to me?  Thanks!